# Проблема с работой arc4random

Tags: xcode, ios

Добрый день.

Столкнулся со следующей проблемой: есть вот такой код:

```
- (IBAction)randomButton:(id)sender
{
int v = arc4random() %3;
if (v==1)
{
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"1" message:@"" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Back" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertView show];
}
if (v==2)
{
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"2" message:@"" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Back" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertView show];
}
if (v==3)
{
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"3" message:@"" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Back" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertView show];
}
}
```

Но почему-то при нажатии на кнопку никогда не выдается значение номера 3, только 1 и 2, сколько бы я не клацал.
Помогите, пожалуйста, найти ошибку.
Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Потому что нужно добавлять `1`.

`arc4random()%3` будет выдавать значения `0`, `1`, `2`

Решение: `1+arc4random()%3;`

Comment: Не 1, а 2. Так как при добавлении единицы шанс выпадения 3 всё равно меньше, чем у 1 и 2.

Answer (score 1):

Оператор `%` возвращает *остаток от деления*. А остаток от деления никогда не будет равен делителю (в этом случае можно добавить 1 к результату деления, и остаток будет 0).